# how to fix when selenium hangs?

Tags: selenium

Sometimes selenium hangs. Is there a way that I can increase the memory or timeout settings for selenium so that it does not hang as much? When running tests that take a lot of memory, sometimes the job hangs and doesn't finish.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Selenium Webdriver, you can add implicit wait statement as shown below:
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)